# Solidity 'real' type and fixed point regimes

Tags: solidity

I'm sure I read somewhere that Solidity had a fixed point type 'real' of format 32byte.32byte, though [the docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html) say Fixed Point numbers are still to come.

Until it's implemented, is there any best practice or existing library for Fixed Point maths?

Comment: Maybe this is what you need: https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.md

Comment: It's 2020 and many things changed in the meantime. Check out my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-arithmetic-libraries-are-there-available-for-solidity/83786#83786), I made a compilation of all the fixed/float point libraries available for Solidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is the one Ethereum itself takes: represent everything in terms of an atomic unit that's smaller than you're likely to need. Ether is represented in Ethereum as 'wei', with 10^18 wei being one ether. All operations being in this unit make the math trivial, and values are divided down when required for display to users.

Comment: Yeah I can understand that.  Just trying to gauge the direction of development and future proof a bit if needed.
I'm also confusing myself a bit with the fixed point stuff. With a background in micro controller (to which ethereum bares more than a passing resemblance sans shift left/right ops), I'm use to thinking in base 2 fixed point and not based 10 to which I'm realising the luxury of a 256bit word!  But no matter, I'll just go with an arbitrary base 10 scaling factor.